# How to retrieve table dynamically using only one controller?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, odbc

I am using the following code as a controller for a single table to access the table from my database, and assign values of each column to a variable. However, I have many tables(Booktrans in this case) and I want to use a single controller that can access all the tables using table ID as a variable. After that, assigning values of different columns from different tables will also be different from the code below. Could anyone help me with a "dynamic" way of coding to replace this controller for a specific table with a dynamic controller?

I am using MVC4.

All the tables have different structures and different column names.

```
public ActionResult Booktrans()
{
    String connectionString = "Dsn=SECURE;Uid=internwebuser";
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM booktrans";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);

    var model = new List<Booktrans>(); 

    using (conn)
    {
        conn.Open();
        OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //model = new List<Booktrans>();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            var book = new Booktrans();
            book.ship_last_name = rdr["ship_last_name"].ToString();
            book.ship_first_name = rdr["ship_first_name"].ToString();
            book.ship_zip = rdr["ship_zip"].ToString();
            book.ship_state = rdr["ship_state"].ToString();
            book.ship_address = rdr["ship_address"].ToString();
            book.ship_city = rdr["ship_city"].ToString();
            book.day_phone = rdr["day_phone"].ToString();
            book.email_address = rdr["email_address"].ToString();


            model.Add(book);
        }

    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting a list of dynamic types or strong types ( Ex : `Booktrans` ) ?

Comment: I don't quite follow your question. I have the following as my view for that controller. I don't want to have a controller each for all the tables. 

@ foreach (var book in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@ book.ship_first_name @ book.ship_last_name</td>
                <td>@ book.ship_address
                    <br />
                    @ book.ship_city, @ book.ship_state @ book.ship_zip</td>
                <td>Day phone: @ book.day_phone
                    <br />
                    Email: @ book.email_address</td>
            </tr>
        }

Comment: `After that, assigning values of different columns from different tables will also be different from the code below` - This statement alone should tell you that something "smells" by trying to combine all of this into a single function.  If each table is different and the columns in those tables are different, you should have different functions!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: @Shyju - he is wanting the code to dynamically figure out what table it is querying from and switch the return based on the table type.  Basically, combine your entire DAL into a single function is how I interpreted this.

Comment: The reason i asked is, He might be able to return a list of dynamic types, like Dapper does.

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid using the SQL command ("SELECT * FROM ...") and instead use functions with variables storing table id. I'm sorry if this is confusing. Having controllers for every table is a lot of redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use an actual ORM, since that's what you're trying to reverse-engineer here. With something like Entity Framework, you create an entity class that maps to a particular table and that has properties that map to columns in that table. Then, with Entity Framework, in particular, you add a `DbSet` that represent the collection of rows in this table to your context:

```
public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

With that, you can then simply use the API Entity Framework provides to interact with that data:

```
// Get specific Foo
var foo = db.Foos.Find(id);

// Get matching Foos
var foos = db.Foos.Where(m => m.Bar == "bar");

// Add a new Foo
db.Foos.Add(new Foo { Bar = "bar" });
```

So on and so forth. Other ORMS like NHibernate have slight different setups and API, but they all basically behave the same and don't require that you worry about generating SQL.